# Spring JDBC Adapter in Cluster mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using spring JDBC inbound channel adapter in my web application. If I deploy this application in clustered environment,  two or more instances pickup the same job and run.
Can anybody help to overcome this issue by changing the spring configuration ?
I have attached my spring configuration.

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter 
    query=" SELECT JOBID,
                   JOBKEY,
                   JOBPARAM                    
              FROM BATCHJOB 
             WHERE JOBSTATUS = 'A' "  
    max-rows-per-poll="1" channel="inboundAdhocJobTable" data-source="dataSource" 
    row-mapper="adhocJobMapper"
    update=" delete from BATCHJOB where JOBKEY in (:jobKey)"
     >
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" >
            <int:advice-chain>              
            </int:advice-chain>
        </int:poller>       

</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this will not be possible without some sort of syncing. Additionally using the database as some sort of message queue is not a good idea (http://mikehadlow.blogspot.de/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html). I'd try to follow different approaches:

1. Use some sort of message bus + message store to store the jobs objects rather than executing SQL directly. In this case you'll have to change the way jobs are being stored. Either by using some sort of message store backed channel (Spring integration only) or push them to a message queue like RabbitMQ to store these jobs.
2. I'm not 100% sure but remember that Spring Batch offers something similar like Master-Slave-Job splitting and synchronization. Maybe you have a look there.